# Why doesn't my script work, even when I run it as an administrator?

Tags: python, windows, access-denied

I'm trying to write a Python script that blocks websites. It should modify the hosts file, however, even when I run the command as an admin, it denies access.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime as dt

hosts_path = r"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
redirect = "127.0.0.1"
website_list = ["www.facebook.com", "facebook.com"]

while True:
    if dt(dt.now().year,
          dt.now().month,
          dt.now().day, 1) < dt.now() < dt(dt.now().year,
                                           dt.now().month,
                                           dt.now().day, 16):
        print("working time")
        with open(hosts_path, 'r+') as file:
            content = file.read()
            for website in website_list:
                if website in content:
                    pass
                else:
                    file.write(redirect + " " + website + "\n")
    else:
        with open(hosts_path, 'r+') as file:
            content = file.readlines()
            file.seek(0)
            for line in content:
                if not any(website in line for website in website_list):
                    file.write(line)
            file.truncate()
        print("fun hours")
    time.sleep(5)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: How do you know it's running as administrator? Show us the command line.

Comment: @Mark Ransom I ran the python program through command prompt admin version(by right clicking it and choosing admin version). I do not see an option to add a screenshot here..

Comment: What is the Windows error number (`winerror`, not `errno`) that's set on the exception?

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
working time
  File "C:/Users/Ayush/Desktop/Computer Science/FinalIA.py", line 19, in <module>
    with open(hosts_path, 'r+') as file:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts'` @eryksun this is exactly what it's saying, not too sure whats a winerror.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot Python's I/O implementation doesn't return the underlying Windows error. Please run the following snippet of code: `exec("""import ctypes,_winapi\ntry:\n    h = _winapi.CreateFile('C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts', 0xC0000000, 3, 0, _winapi.OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0)\nexcept OSError:\n    print(ctypes.windll.ntdll.RtlGetLastNtStatus())\n    raise\n""")`. This attempts to open the file with generic read-write access (0xC0000000) and read-write sharing (3). If it fails, please reply with the printed system status code (should be negative) and WinError code.

Comment: @eryksun i tried running it on python, got this error`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied`

Comment: The except handler should have printed a negative status code from `RtlGetLastNtStatus` before the traceback was shown. Which version of Python is this? Is it standard Windows Python 3.x? If so, the ctypes code should have worked.

Comment: @eryksun Yea its python 3.7. I have no idea what went wrong and why is it not running, i can edit hosts file from notepad using admin mode but the program is not runnning it. Any leads?

Comment: I was looking for the status code as a possible lead. Windows maps several status codes to `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (5). Anyway, let's make sure you're really elevated. Check the output from the following command: `os.system('whoami /groups | findstr /i "admin label"')`. It should include two enabled admin groups (S-1-5-114  and S-1-5-32-544) and the high integrity label (S-1-16-12288).